# Mocking $emit event of a child component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a snackbar component which I am writing tests for. It contains a child component (A button, when clicked closes the snackbar).

This button emits a `@click` event which the parent listens to and runs a method to either close the snackbar or open another.

Is there a way of mocking the `$emit`? I can't seem to find something anywhere related to this.

```
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/vue';
import Snackbar from '../Snackbar.vue';
import EventBus from '@/services/EventBus';

describe('Snackbar', () => {
    const role = 'alert';
    
    it('should close snackbar on button click', async () => {
        const type = 'success';

        const { getByRole } = render(Snackbar, {
            // with this the button is inaccessible
            stubs: ['OBButton'],
        });

        await EventBus.$emit('addSnack', {
            type,
        });

        const snackbar = getByRole('alert');

        // this is wrong...
        await fireEvent.click(button);
  
        // this expect should be appropriate.
        expect(snackbar).not.toBeInTheDocument;
    });
});
```

This is the template of the component:

```
<template>
    <div class="snackbar-wrapper elevated">
        <transition name="snack-slide" v-on:after-leave="checkForMoreSnacks">
            <div
                role="alert"
                class="snack-data"
                v-if="currentSnack != null"
            >
                <span class="snack-text">{{ currentSnack.text }}</span>
                <OBButton
                    :text="currentSnack.buttonText"
                    @click="closeCurrentSnack"
                    :type="buttonType"
                ></OBButton>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
```

Additional Info:

1. This component is never unmounted. Closing it means setting the `currentSnack` value to `null` which hides it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is quite simple:

```
import ButtonComponent from '@/components/ButtonComponent.vue';

const { getByRole, getByText } = render(Snackbar, {
  components: { ButtonComponent } ,
  mocks: { $t: msg => msg }
})
```

After which point you can use this component like such:

```
const button = getByRole('button');
```

Answer (score 8):

Use trigger to emit an event from a child component. You could do:

```js
import ButtonComponent from '@/components/ButtonComponent.vue';
import Snackbar from '@/components/Snackbar.vue';

it('should foo', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Snackbar);
  wrapper.find(ButtonComponent).trigger('click');
  // Your assertions here

})
```

EDIT: For a custom event is more tricky. I am currently mocking the event like this:

```js
const wrapper = shallowMount(Snackbar);
const childWrapper = wrapper.find(ButtomComponent);
childWrapper.vm.$emit('custom', { foo: 'bar' })
```

Comment: Custom vue event emission is unfortunately using @vue/test-utils and not @testing-library/vue

Comment: In your second example `childWrapper.vm` is `undefined`. You probably would like to change `wrapper.find(ButtomComponent)` to `wrapper.getComponent(ButtomComponent)`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to trigger an emit to test the snackbar. In that case you can use Vue.JS trigger functionality, which triggers an event asynchronously in the wrapper DOM.

You can find more information here : https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/trigger.html

Also, for testing $emit, you can find more information here: https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/testing-emitted-events.html#write-a-component-and-test

Comment: Unfortuately, I've already been through that documentation. Hasn't really helped me. Would it be possible to provide some kind of specific code that I can try to implement? I know its a tough ask so no worries if not.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you are looking to do?

Comment: I want to trigger the emit the child component (the button) fires which calls the method that closes (or more approproiately hides) the snackbar.